# Mysql select between two dates won't work

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I want to SELECT row BETWEEN two dates(date1 and date2) from table. I have experienced this problem but I don't know why it won't work this time. I only have 1 row in my receipt table with timestamp : 2015-05-29 22:09:44.
And I have tried these syntaxs:

```
SELECT * FROM receipt
WHERE (date BETWEEN 2015-05-22
AND 2015-05-30) //not work even with date_format()

SELECT * FROM receipt
WHERE date > 22-05-2015 AND date < 30-05-2015 //not work even with date_format()

SELECT * FROM receipt
WHERE date > 22-05-2015 //work but when I changed to date > 22-07-2015 it's still select row (my timestamp is may 2015)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM receipt
WHERE DATE(`date`) BETWEEN '2015-05-22' AND '2015-05-30'
```

Comment: A better formulation is `date >= '2015-05-22' and date < '2015-05-31'`, because this method allows the query to take advantage of an index on `date`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  blahblah 
FROM receipt
WHERE thedate >= '2014-12-01 00:00:00' 
  AND thedate <= '2015-05-06 00:00:00'
```

Comment: So I use PHP variable WHERE date >  '.date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($yesterday)).'; and give me error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12:00:00' at line 5.

Comment: Echo out your php string and focus on just that to start

Comment: And alter table changing date column named 'date' to something not error prone